# How to export custom database data to excel file

Tags: ajax, export, csv

Hi everyone I have the code below, but when I click on the link generated a new page is open with 0 display on it. 
What I'm doing wrong?

```
function list_reservation_to_csv() {

 global $wpdb;
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'prenotazione_eventi';
 $file = 'email_csv'; // ?? not defined in original code
 $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name",ARRAY_A);

 if (empty($results)) {
   return;
 }

 $csv_output = '"'.implode('";"',array_keys($results[0])).'";'."\n";;

 foreach ($results as $row) {
  $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"',$row).'";'."\n";
 }
 $csv_output .= "\n";

 $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
 header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
 print $csv_output;
 exit;

 }
add_action('wp_ajax_csv_pull','list_reservation_to_csv');

$ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=csv_pull');

<a href="<?php echo $ajax_url; ?>"><button>Scarica csv</button></a>
```

Comment: Are you displaying PHP errors? If this is the literal source code, it's bound not to work because PHP and HTML code are intermixed. Turn error reporting on; without it all people can do is guess.

Comment: nope, no errors. Now I'm thinking... wp_ajax_csv_pull action works only in frontend or also in backend?

Comment: If the code is literally like it is above, there is bound to be a syntax error on the last line though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [nopriv hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action))

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_csv_pull','list_reservation_to_csv');
```

This adds the option to run the function without being logged in as a registered user.

Comment: nope, same problem

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: try dumping data early and see what you get. ie: after `$results = $wpdb-> ...` do a var_dump($results). If that looks ok, move to the next point where you alter the data and so on. Also, try replacing `print $csv_output;` with `print_r($csv_output);` or `echo $csv_output;`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [WPAllExport](https://www.wpallimport.com/export-wordpress/) plugin; it's super customisable, and it's doing a bunch of the heavy lifting. I've used it successfully to manage the exporting of event data in super complex situations, and I know it would do a great job. (I'm not affiliated in any way with it; I'm just a happy customer.)

I generally try to find out if someone has already attempted to solve the problem that I have. In the WordPress environment, most things have already been solved.